# Is a compact aspherical 3-manifold irreducible

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M^3$ be a compact $3$-manifold (possibly with boundary). Suppose $M$ is aspherical, can we show that $M$ must be irreducible? Here, irreducible means any embedded sphere in $M$ bounds a $3$-ball.

Comment: Have you looked at an introductory 3-manifolds notes, like Hatcher or Jaco?

Comment: @RyanBudney The related result in Hatcher's book is Proposition 3.10, which states that if $\pi_2=0$, any embedded sphere bounds a contractible 3-manifold. This 3-manifold is a 3-ball if we use the result of Poincare's conjecture. I was wonder if there exists a more direct proof for this fact.

Comment: You absolutely need PC for this, as this statement implies PC.

Comment: Imagine that the PC fails and $\Sigma$ is a fake 3-dimensional sphere. Take the connected sum $M=T^3 \# \Sigma$. Now, prove that $M$ is aspherical but reducible.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right.